# Spring boot initialization is not reading from hibernate.properties

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to create a very basic Spring Boot web application, using Spring Boot, Hibernate and MySQL. The basic objective is to convert a complex JSON to a cascaded set of POJOs and persist in the database. In `hibernate.properties` I configured `Mysql5InnodbDialect`, but the initialization goes for a different dialect. Hope the following log is enough for an explanation, nevertheless would post if more information is needed.

```
2019-04-06 10:25:36.448  INFO 2256 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}

2019-04-06 10:25:36.448  INFO 2256 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect, hibernate.show_sql=true, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=UPDATE, hibernate.format_sql=true}

2019-04-06 10:25:36.511  INFO 2256 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}

2019-04-06 10:25:36.573  INFO 2256 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Spring Boot apps don’t read hibernate.properties by default. Place them under “spring.jpa.hibernate” in application.properties

Comment: modified code accordingly and got the hibernate related properties read by the application. thanks Strelok.

Comment: The `hibernate.properties` are read by Hibernate and not Spring Boot. `hibernate.properties` is the default read by Hibernate (as explained in the Hibernate reference). So no Spring Boot shouldn't load this file. However you should actually be placing those properties in the `application.properties` file and in your case something like `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect`

Answer (score 0):

Can you be trying to scan your application properties file in Spring Boot?

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.virus.shopingcart.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.virus.shopingcart.*")
@ComponentScan("com.virus.shopingcart.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ShopingBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ShopingBoot.class, args);
    }   
}
```